# The babel library does not work with the \tikzset command inside the document environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel-french

Here is an example with the `angle` option of the `Straight Barb arrow` using the colon character `:`

```
\tikzset{>={Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}}
```

The error is

> ! Paragraph ended before \pgfarrowsfourparameters@ was
>   complete.

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{babel,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,babel}
\begin{document}

% inside the environment document, babel library doesnt work
\tikzset{>={Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{>={Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}}
\draw[<->](0,0)--(2,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course not, I took the trouble to write a minimal example and you still have to look for problems where there are none. When the document is composed of several pages and several tikzpicture environments, it is better to assign the arrows globally and not locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `\tikzset` is located in the preamble, the Ti*k*Z `babel` library works.

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{babel,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,babel}
% In the preamble, babel library work
\tikzset{>={Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->](0,0)--(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Inside the document environment, it is necessary to place `\tikzset` between the `\shorthandoff{:}` and `\shorthandon{:}`

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{babel,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,babel}

\begin{document}
% Between the command \shorthandoff{:} and \shorthandon{:}, no more problems
\shorthandoff{:}
\tikzset{>={Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}} 
\shorthandon{:}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{>={Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}}
\draw[<->](0,0)--(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In both cases, we get:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yes, nice. In other languages (looking at you, `spanish`) you need `\deactivatequoting`. With the modern utf8 setup all these tricks are not so useful anymore... It would be nice if babel had a option with "stop any catcode game"...

Comment: Since March 25, 2018, `utf8` is the default encoding for LaTeX, see: [utf8 as standard](https://www.texdev.net/2018/03/25/latex2e-utf-8-as-standard/) Nevertheless, I have this problem with Babel. It would indeed be nice if the `\tikzset` command or the `babel library` could be fixed.

Comment: Regarding the sentence “When `\tikzset` is located in the preamble, the TikZ `babel` library works.”: as far as I know, babel-french doesn't make the characters `:;!?`  active before `\begin{document}`. So, saying that the “TikZ `babel` library works” in this case might be a bit far-fetched...

Comment: @frougon Indeed, the more I think about this problem, the less I can understand its cause. Is it the command `\tikzset`? the `babel` library? or is it the `document environment`?

Comment: @AndréC TikZ has to parse input where some characters (here ,`:`) aren't the same from TeX's point of view for everyone (depending on use of the optional use of `babel` and the chosen language). I don't know the implementation, but this is not an easy situation. Back in the days, you couldn't even use `\label{fig:foobar}` in LaTeX with an active `:` character... Why don't you use `\tikzset` in the preamble if it works there?

Comment: @Rmano Do you mean `shorthands=off`? :-)

Comment: @frougon According to page `35` of the `3.1.3` manual , the command `\tikzset` must be at the beginning of the document and in this case, there is a problem. Nevertheless, on page `70`, we learn that this command `\tikzset` can be placed in the preamble.
I posted this question because it took me several hours to identify the cause of the error. And I indicate in the solution, two different ways to solve this problem including placement in the preamble.

Comment: @AndréC One can probably agree that “beginning of the document” doesn't necessarily mean “beginning of the `document` environment”. :-)

Comment: @JavierBezos, yes, it works, but if `babel` has been `Require`ed in a class, I have to use `\deactivatequoting`...

Comment: @frougon If this were the case, it would not be specified in the preamble on page `70`.

Comment: @AndréC Huh? You said yourself [in your own answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495092/73317) that there is no problem when `\tikzset` is used in the preamble. Therefore, the sentence on page 70 (“Ilka has moved the style definition to the preamble by saying `\tikzset{terminal/.style=...}` (...)”) gives working advice according to your own sayings, as opposed to using `\tikzset` in the `document` environment outside any `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @frougon I don't understand you. If the manual said it was absolutely necessary to place `\tikzset` in the preamble, it would be written in plain language. The examples in the manual place `\tikzset` both in the `document` environment and within the `tikzpicture` environment itself (see for example page `143`). In other words, there is nothing in the manual to indicate where the `\tikzset` command should be located. 

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: @AndréC You still haven't pointed any place in the manual suggesting to put `\tikzset` in a place where it might cause problems. On page 143, `\tikzset` is used inside the `\tikzpicture` environment; it works quite fine there even with `[french]{babel}`, as shown by this example: `\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{babel,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{>={Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}}
\draw[<->](0,0)--(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.

Comment: @frougon I don't understand your problem.

Comment: @AndréC I have no problem. I didn't ask the question on this page. Never mind.

Comment: @Rmano Usually `\PassOptionsToPackage{shorthands=off}{babel}` before loading the class does the trick.