# Problem with babel and TikZ if any of russian, ngerman, spanish or portuguese are used

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel

The `tikzpicture` in the MWE compiles without problems for `greek`, `French`, `Italian` and `English` but, if any of `Russian`, `ngerman`, `Spanish` or `Portuguese` is added to `babel`, `ERROR ! Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again> \alpha l.32 pic ["$\alpha$", draw, fill=yellow] {angle = F--X--A} The control sequence marked <to be read again> should not appear between \csname and \endcsname` is produced.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 1 July 2019
%=======================
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usepackage[greek,french,italian,english]{babel}
%\usepackage[greek,russian,ngerman,french,spanish,italian,portuguese,english]{babel}
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[angle radius=.75cm]
\node (A) at (-2,0) [red,left] {$A$};
\node (B) at ( 3,.5) [red,right] {$B$};
\node (C) at (-2,2) [blue,left] {$C$};
\node (D) at ( 3,2.5) [blue,right] {$D$};
\node (E) at (60:-5mm) [below] {$E$};
\node (F) at (60:3.5cm) [above] {$F$};
\coordinate (X) at (intersection cs:first line={(A)--(B)}, second line={(E)--(F)});
\coordinate (Y) at (intersection cs:first line={(C)--(D)}, second line={(E)--(F)});
\path
(A) edge [red, thick] (B)
(C) edge [blue, thick] (D)
(E) edge [thick] (F)
pic ["$\alpha$", draw, fill=yellow] {angle = F--X--A}
pic ["$\beta$", draw, fill=green!30] {angle = B--X--F}
pic ["$\gamma$", draw, fill=yellow] {angle = E--Y--D}
pic ["$\delta$", draw, fill=green!30] {angle = C--Y--E};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495091/the-babel-library-does-not-work-with-the-tikzset-command-inside-the-document-en. Try adding `shorthands=off` in the babel options, or putting `\deactivatequoting` at the start of your document.

Comment: I realize there is a long trail of questions dealing with problems between 'babel' and 'tikz', at least one of them my own regarding a clash of the `quotation environments` generated by package `quotation` with that of `babel-Spanish`, at the time answered by @egreg, but none quite address the problem I have struck here, involving several languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `shorthands=off` works:

```
\usepackage[greek,russian,ngerman,french,spanish,italian,portuguese,english, shorthands=off]{babel}
```

But now you should also use

```latex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

or use one of the unicode-based engines.