# Having trouble with TikZ -- For Loop and Conditionals

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, loops, ifthenelse

Essentially what I am trying to achieve is a grid of 12 circles with three rows and four columns. All I would like is for the two middle columns to be red while the other two columns are black. Here is my current attempt, which gives me all red circles no matter what I do.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x in {0,...,3}{
    \foreach \y in {0,...,2}{
        \ifthenelse{\x in {1,2}}{
            \draw[red,fill=red] (\x,\y) circle (0.4);
        }{
            \draw (\x,\y) circle (0.4);
        }
    }
}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Current Result with Above TikZ Code:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There's no “in” test for `\ifthenelse`.

Comment: Code has been edited, now I am attempting only the second columng or x=1, still getting the same result

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x in {0,...,3}{
    \foreach \y in {0,...,2}{
        \ifthenelse{\x = 1}{
            \draw[red,fill=red] (\x,\y) circle (0.4);
        }{
            \draw (\x,\y) circle (0.4);
        }
    }
}
 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: ...as @egreg said, there is no `in` test for `ifthenelse`. Try `\ifthenelse{\x < 3}` or similar.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5):

You already know matrix dimensions, only twelve nodes. They are easy to manage. Then you can use a `matrix` and forget `foreach` and `ifthenelse` problems ;-)

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, 
    row sep=2mm, column sep=2mm,
    nodes={circle, draw, minimum width=8mm},
    column 2/.style={nodes={red, fill=red}},
    column 3/.style={nodes={red, fill=red}},
    ]
    { &&&\\&&&\\&&&\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As said by @greg in the comment, there is no such a thing as a `\x in {1,2}` test for `ifthenelse`.

After reading the documentation for the package `xifthen`, you can:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,...,3}{
    \foreach \y in {0,...,2}{
        \ifthenelse{\x > 0 \AND \x < 3}{
            \draw[red,fill=red] (\x,\y) circle (0.4);
        }{
            \draw (\x,\y) circle (0.4);
        }
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in: 
[image: white and red discs]

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use `ifthen`. A [pgf membership test](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501895) can be used to implement your condition `\x in {1,2}`,

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{memberQ}{2}{%
  \begingroup%
    \edef\pgfutil@tmpb{0}%
    \edef\pgfutil@tmpa{#2}%
    \expandafter\pgfmath@member@i\pgfutil@firstofone#1\pgfmath@token@stop
    \edef\pgfmathresult{\pgfutil@tmpb}%
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult%
  \endgroup}
\def\pgfmath@member@i#1{%
    \ifx\pgfmath@token@stop#1%
    \else
      \ifnum#1=\pgfutil@tmpa\relax%
      \gdef\pgfutil@tmpb{1}%
      %\typeout{#1=\pgfutil@tmpa}
      \fi%
      \expandafter\pgfmath@member@i
    \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \isMember using {int(memberQ({1,2},\x))}] in {0,...,3}{
    \foreach \y in {0,...,2}{
        \draw \ifnum\isMember=1
        [red,fill=red]
        \fi (\x,\y) circle[radius=0.4cm];
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This membership test works *unless* the last entry of the list has a substructure. Similar limitations apply to the `dim` function, which is built in `pgf`, but not mentioned in the manual, presumably for that reason. However, as long as you have ordinary lists, both `memberQ` and `dim` do work properly. (Proposed alternatives with a much more extensive codes also have drawbacks, sometimes even more severe, and I wish that those who propose them would mention them, too.)

As you can see, an ordinary `\ifnum` can be built into the path.

```
\draw \ifnum\itest=1
    [red,fill=red]
    \fi (\x,\y) circle[radius=0.4cm];
```

You then only have to draw one path. You can also use the conventional `ifthenelse` instead of the `memberQ` function.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \itest using {int(ifthenelse(\x>0 && \x <3,1,0))}] in {0,...,3}{
    \foreach \y in {0,...,2}{
        \draw \ifnum\itest=1
        [red,fill=red]
        \fi (\x,\y) circle[radius=0.4cm];
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this case you do not even have to use `evaluate`, you can simply use the fact that `\numexpr` truncates the result,

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x  in {0,...,3}{
    \foreach \y in {0,...,2}{
        \draw \ifnum\the\numexpr\x/2\relax=1
        [red,fill=red]
        \fi (\x,\y) circle[radius=0.4cm];
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for the pleasure of using the modulo function.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x in {0,...,3}{
    \foreach \y [evaluate =\x as \coloring using {int(Mod(\x,3))}]in {0,...,2}{
     \ifthenelse{\coloring = 0}{
            \draw (\x,\y) circle (0.4);
        }{
            \draw[red,fill=red] (\x,\y) circle (0.4);
        }
    }
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such test for `\ifthenelse`. However, you can use a different implementation, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467527/4427

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz} % for the application

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifthenelse}{mmm}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_eq:NN \numtest     \int_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \oddtest     \int_if_odd_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \fptest      \fp_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \dimtest     \dim_compare_p:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \deftest     \cs_if_exist_p:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \namedeftest \cs_if_exist_p:c
\cs_new_eq:NN \eqdeftest   \token_if_eq_meaning_p:NN
\cs_new_eq:NN \streqtest   \str_if_eq_p:ee
\cs_new_eq:NN \emptytest   \tl_if_blank_p:n
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \xxifthen_legacy_conditional:n { p,T,F,TF }
 {
  \use:c { if#1 } \prg_return_true: \else: \prg_return_false: \fi:
 }
\cs_new_eq:NN \boolean \xxifthen_legacy_conditional_p:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x in {0,...,3}{
    \foreach \y in {0,...,2}{
        \xifthenelse{\numtest{1 <= \x <= 2}}{
            \draw[red,fill=red] (\x,\y) circle (0.4);
        }{
            \draw (\x,\y) circle (0.4);
        }
    }
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]